# How many times has the in-production Robotech live action movie changed director already?

Tags: movie, behind-the-scenes, production, robotech

A Robotech live action movie was first announced in 2007. Since then, they changed company, and a different director was announced more than once. Yesterday, I saw the new of an Argentine "Andrés Muschietti" taking over the direction of the movie. How many times has the in-production Robotech live action movie changed director already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Twice

Early 2013: The Hollywood Reporter announces that Warner Bros. is in talks with commercial director Nick Mathieu to [direct the film](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/warner-bros-chooses-robotech-director-415144).

July 24, 2013: Leonardo DiCaprio turns down a role in Star Wars: Episode VII and has shown interest to [star as a main character](http://uk.ign.com/articles/2013/07/24/leonardo-dicaprio-interested-in-robotech-movie) in the upcoming big screen version of Robotech. Nick Mathieu is directing the movie at this point.

February 4, 2015: Deadline.com reports Gianni Nunori and Mark Canton have selected Michael B. Gordon to write the film's script and are looking at [Andy Muschietti to direct it](http://deadline.com/2015/02/robotech-movie-hollywood-gang-1201364914/), after some setbacks to production. Obviously, Nick Mathieu is no longer the director.

March 25, 2015: Variety announces that the Robotech franchise has been [acquired by Sony Pictures](http://variety.com/2015/film/news/robotech-movie-sony-tv-series-anime-1201460191/), who views Robotech as a potential film franchise. Andy Muschietti never got the directing role before Sony bought the rights, so at this point the movie has only ever had one director: Mathieu.

April 29, 2015: Deadline reports that James Wan is in talks to [direct the film](http://deadline.com/2015/04/james-wan-robotech-director-talks-sony-1201418183/).

June 3, 2015: The Hollywood Reporter reports that Wan is confirmed to [direct the film](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/james-wan-closes-deals-direct-799686).

July 17, 2017: The Hollywood Reporter reports that Andy Muschietti will [direct the film](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/robotech-movie-director-andy-muschietti-direct-1021744), after Wan drops out to work on Aquaman.

To summarise:

1st Director - Nick Mathieu
2nd Director - James Wan
3rd Director (Current) - Andy Muschietti

It's also worth noting that the deal with Sony hasn't actually been finalised yet, so there's every possibility of it falling through and production getting thrown up in the air again.

Comment: That's a very detailed summary, but I remember there were many articles about former spiderman actor Tobey Maguire directing the movie prior 2013 in Robotech-related blogs and forums. Is it complete?

Comment: Maguire and his production company, _Maguire Entertainment_, were producing the film, but Maguire himself was never directing it. In fact, he was looking to snap up the lead role instead.

Comment: He's too old for the lead role now. Playing a 17 years old teenager with 30 is one thing, playing a 19 years old teenager with 42 or more it wont be belieable

Comment: @Pablo [It may not be as unbelievable as you think](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75534/who-was-the-oldest-actor-to-play-a-teenager).

Comment: oh well, in the case of Tony Maguire then. Yes, I know there was also a soccer player of 17 years old from Africa that got a rumour he was 41 and the rumour got so big that they had to actually check his birth certificate to confirm his age. This happened in Italy in a club playing in the second division

Comment: Now it's three times. Could you update the answer? https://www.superherohype.com/movies/513673-hawkeye-director-rhys-thomas-will-helm-sonys-robotech-movie